# Pandas read_csv BZ2 File Always Includes File Name

Tags: pandas, bzip2

Every time I load a .bz2 file into a Pandas dataframe I get the name of the file as the first column of the first row of the dataframe. I'm using `tar` to compress the files. I have written the following `something.txt` file:

```
1  2  3  4   5
2  3  4  5   6
6  7  8  9  10
```

I compress it via `tar -cvjf something.txt.bz2 something.txt`. Then, I decompress the data and move it to a secure file location:

```
tar -xvjf something.txt.bz2 
mv something.txt something.txt.2
```

Now I load the data in a python script in three different ways:

```
>>> data1 = pd.read_csv("something.txt")
>>> data2 = pd.read_csv("something.txt.2")
>>> data3 = pd.read_csv("something.txt.bz2")
```

and here's what i get when I read these data back again:

```
>>> data1
   1  2  3  4   5
0  2  3  4  5   6
1  6  7  8  9  10
>>> data2
   1  2  3  4   5
0  2  3  4  5   6
1  6  7  8  9  10
>>> data3
   something.txt    2    3    4     5
0            2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0   6.0
1            6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
2            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Does anybody know why this is happening???

Comment: Have you tried to specify the compression in read_csv like `pd.read_csv("something.txt.bz2", compression='bz2')`. By default it is 'infer', so maybe the problem comes from there?

Comment: yes, I tried that. This is a MYSTERY!

Comment: I must say, I was dealing with the same issue as you, and it was due to using `tar` instead of `bzip2` to compress a single file.  Please see what has worked for me below in the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works on my end.  First, consider your data set `something.txt`:

```
"c0" "c1" "c2" "c3" "c4"
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
6 7 8 9 10
```

where I named the columns and used a single space as a separator for consistency.  Then, compress it by using `bzip2` (**not** `tar`):

```bash
bzip2 -z9 something.txt
```

This will replace `something.txt` with `something.txt.bz2` in your base directory.  Finally, initiate a python session and perform the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("something.txt.bz2", compression="bz2", sep=" ")
df
```

The last line will print:

```bash
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5   6
2   6   7   8   9  10
```

which shows the expected values.
I hope this helps!